# trying to put -lglew and -lfreeglut for netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Programming in OpenGL (attempting to) and I put -lglew and -lfreeglut into Project>properties>build>linker>compilation line>additional options

Here is my code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
// Local Utilities Includes
#include "vgl.h"
#include "LoadShaders.h"
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
// Some constants (different from book)
const int Triangles = 0; // The index of the "Triangles" vertex array
const int NumVAOs = 1; // The number of vertex array objects (VAOs)
const int ArrayBuffer = 0; // The index of the array buffer (0)
const int NumBuffers = 1; // The total number of buffers
const int vPosition = 0; // The starting index of the vertex position attribute
GLuint VAOs[NumVAOs]; // An array of vertex array objects
GLuint Buffers[NumBuffers]; // An array of buffers
const GLuint NumVertices = 6; // 6 total vertices in 2 triangles
void init()
{
// Have OpenGL allocate NumVAOs vertex array object names for our use
// The IDs of these objects are returned in the VAOs array
glGenVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);
// Bind a vertex array object by creating one (with the name provided
// as an argument) and set that object to "active"
// If 0 is passed in, returns vertex objects to default state
// GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated if array is not a valid value
glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
// Create an array of vertices
GLfloat vertices[NumVertices][2] = {
{ -0.9, -0.9 },
{ 0.85, -0.9 },
{ -0.9, 0.85 },
{ 0.9, -0.85 },
{ 0.9, 0.9 },
{ -0.85, 0.9} };
// Same with glGenVertexArrays, but do so with buffers
glGenBuffers( NumBuffers, Buffers );
// Bind the current one as an array buffer
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer] );
// Provide data for the bound array buffer from our vertices array
// Could generate a GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
// At least two shaders MUST be supplied:
// 1) vertex shader, which will set vertex data
// 2) fragment shader, which will deal with primitives
ShaderInfo shaders[] = {
{GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert"},
{GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triangles.frag"},
{GL_NONE, NULL }
};
// Helper function to load the shaders (in downloadable code in book)
GLuint program = LoadShaders( shaders );
// Runs the shaders
glUseProgram( program );
// Connect shader's 'in' variable with vertex attribute array
glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
// Enable the vertex attribute array
glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
}
// Function to draw stuff
void display()
{
// Clears the given framebuffer (in this case, color)
// Could set color to clear to with glClearColor, default is black
// Where should we put a call to clearColor?
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
// Same as in init, we want to use the Triangles vertex array object
glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
// Draw routine, send vertex array to OpenGL rendering pipeline
// Draw triangles, starting at offset = 0, and going to NumVertices
// What happens when mode is changed?
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices);
// Force OpenGL commands to begin execution
glFlush();
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// First, initialize data structures and arguments needed by glut
glutInit(&argc, argv);
// We're displaying in RGBA color space
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
// We want a window that 512 by 512 pixels
glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
// We're using OpenGL 4.4 (you should change this to fit yours, need 3.2)
g
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglew
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreeglut

lutInitContextVersion(3,2);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
// Create the window, and call it the name of the first argument)
glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
// To be safe, we're using glew's experimental stuff.
glewExperimental=GL_TRUE;
// Initialize and error check GLEW
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err)
{
// If something went wrong, print the error message
fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
}

// Initialize the display in our program
init();
// The display callback...function called whenever image is redrawn
glutDisplayFunc(display);
// Infinite looping, calling idle function over and over
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

then when I run the program the debug console error says:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/connor/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorldOpenGL'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/helloworldopengl
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/connor/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorldOpenGL'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/helloworldopengl build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o  -lglew -lfreeglut
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglew
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreeglut
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/helloworldopengl] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/connor/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorldOpenGL'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/connor/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorldOpenGL'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 111ms)
```

Am I supposed to do something other than the make all and make install commands while in the directory? I copied over the .h files to /usr/include/GL and the .a files from opengl-redbook.com into /usr/bin manually before I read about the make commands

Comment: also, I don't have an ld directory under /usr/bin

Comment: Capitalize -lglew to -lGLEW and -lfreeglut to -lglut

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

To correctly build your project on Ubuntu, you need to install the following development (-dev) packages, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libglew1.5-dev libglew-dev libglewmx1.5-dev libglewmx-dev freeglut3-dev build-essential
```